# Databinding to nested property - Cannot bind property or column (Winforms)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, .net-4.0

We are running a .NET 4.0 application using Windows Forms. The application uses a single form for two different types of objects.

```
namespace NetIssue
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        B myObj;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            myObj = new B();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", myObj, "c.Message"));
        }
    }

    public class Comment {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }

        public Comment(string msg)
        {
            Message = msg;
        }
    }

    public class A {
        string MyName = "";
    }

    public class B : A {
        public Comment c { get; set; }

        public B()
        {
            c = new Comment("test");
        }
    }
}
```

When the binding above is run in .NET 4.0, we get the error

> An error occured: Cannot bind to the property or column Message on the
>   DataSource. Parameter name: dataMember

However, if we install .NET 4.5 this error goes away.

**Is this a limitation of .NET 4.0, a bug in .NET 4.0, or is something else going on?**

Comment: You don't have any properties in your classes - just fields.

Comment: @IvanStoev Sorry, the actual code uses properties. I updated the example code accordingly. I can't copy / paste the code because it could reveal things about the project. I am building a full reproducible sample now.

Comment: Another thing to mention (except `extends` which I guess is `:`) - class `B` does not have a property `Message` and WF does not support property path like WPF (you cannot use "c.Message")

Comment: @IvanStoev That's what I get for trying to rewrite sample code. (I don't remember which language extends keyword comes from in my head. Maybe PHP.) I updated the code to working code. If you run the code on a machine with .NET 4.5 installed, it will work. If you run it on a .NET 4.0 machine, it will give you a .NET error.

Comment: I see. Actually I learned something from you today! I'm pretty sure property path was not supported, but looks like they added that support later. So may be that's the limitation you are talking about. To verify that, try `textBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", ((B)myObj).c, "Message"));` on .NET 4.0 machine (unfortunately I have no such available right now)

Comment: @IvanStoev I actually just tried it and that is in fact what happened. So this is the answer. Please add it and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short story: Windows Forms data binding doesn't support property path, that's why you are getting the error.

Well, this is what I was thinking until today. But trying your code I was surprised that it **indeed** works on .NET 4.5 machine! So looks like MS has added that at some point - to be honest, have no idea when. But it's there now! Anyway, if backward compatibility is a concern, one should avoid using that feature (although it would be quite pity).

Comment: If only Microsoft had added this for to DataPropertyName of the DataGridView as well, I would have better days.

Answer (score 4):

You can use either of these options:

```
B myObj = new B();
textBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", ((B)myObj).c, "Message"));
```

Or

```
var bs = new BindingSource(myObj, null);
textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "c.Message");
```

Or

```
textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", new B[] { myObj }, "c.Message");
```

Comment: Reza, did you know that? I'm ashamed.

Comment: @IvanStoev didn't know the issue is fixed for a machine running .Net 4.5, but I have used such workaround before. +1 for your good answer :)

Comment: @IvanStoev I couldn't even reproduce the problem on a machine having .Net 2.0 only! So now I don't know why such codes was written while `textBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", myObj, "c.Message"));` worked on a machine with .Net 2.0 only! Am I missing something?

Comment: It's kind of a mistery. Unfortunately I didn't have a clean machine, so can't check. But I'm pretty sure it didn't work when we started with .NET - a long time ago, but I remember it was just after 2.0 (we were waiting for generics). OP seems to be an experienced developer, so I trust what he say. Anyway, as usual, was nice to talk with you! Take care.