# Cannot bind to the property or column "Column Name" on the DataSource. Parameter name: dataMember

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have 2 DTO classes:

```
public class AddressDto
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get: set: }
}

public class CustomerDto
{
    public int Number{ get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public AddressDto Address { get: set: }

    public CustomerDto() 
    {
        Address = new AddressDto();
    }
}
```

I have a form with a binding source in it that binds to `CustomerDto`. I also have a custom control with the address fields. This custom control has a binding source that binds to `AddressDto` The control's textboxes are correctly bound to the address properties.

The control exposes the following property:

```
[Bindable(BindableSupport.Yes, BindingDirection.TwoWay)]
[Browsable(false)]
public object Address
{
    get { return bindingSource.DataSource; }
    set { bindingSource.DataSource = value; }
}
```

On one machine I do not get any errors on `CheckBinding()`. However on another machine I get the above exception when I try to open the form in runtime. In designtime everything works fine.

The control has 3 `TextBoxes` and the designer adds the following bindings:

```
this.bindingSource.AllowNew = true;
this.bindingSource.DataSource = typeof(AddressDto);

this.txtStreet.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", this.bindingSource, "Street", true));
this.txtCity.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", this.bindingSource, "City", true));
this.txtPostCode.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", this.bindingSource, "PostCode", true));
```

Any ideas where the problem can be?

Comment: Are you using property path in your bindings? If yes, it could be similar to this issue [Binding and Polymorphism - Cannot bind property or column (Winforms)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33789575/binding-and-polymorphism-cannot-bind-property-or-column-winforms/33790268#33790268)

Comment: @IvanStoev No. I'm not using property paths.

Comment: How about providing some sort of a [mcve]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I changed the code to:

```
    [Bindable(BindableSupport.Yes, BindingDirection.TwoWay)]
    [Browsable(false)]
    public object Address
    {
        get { return bindingSource.DataSource; }
        set 
        {
            if (value != null && value != System.DBNull.Value)
                bindingSource.DataSource = value;
            else
                bindingSource.DataSource = typeof(AddressDto);
        }
    }
```

Value was `System.DBNull`. With the above change, the exception is not thrown anymore.

This solves the problem. However, why value is `DBNull` is still not clear because I'm using pure POCO classes as my datasources for my bindingsources.

Comment: The winforms databinding was built to target datatables, its ability to bind to objects was boltet on later. That why you get a DBNUll instead of a null.